# Angular7 reactive form material time input validation

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I have an angular 7 reactive form, input field in this form is to let user see and modify time and then using Save() save it back to our db, the problem is that user can enter any none sense numbers in this field which dose not make sense in terms of Time.(like hours should be 1-24, Minutes 1-60)
My question is how can I validate what user entered into time field and if its valid then let Save btn be active?

Note: Based on my testing even though its none sense time entry but while trying to save its not saving to db and its probably sql not letting that happen.

I googled but i could not find anything, also angular has only email Validators which u can put while defining form.

this is my form defination

```
timeForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    Id: new FormControl(''),
    Time: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

and this is my HTML side

```
<form style="background-color: aliceblue;" [formGroup]="service.timeForm">
  <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="120px">
    <mat-grid-tile>
      <div class="form-controles-container">
        <input type="hidden" formControlName="Id" />
        <mat-form-field>
          <input formControlName="Time" matInput placeholder="Time" />
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="button-row">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)="Save()">Save</button>
          <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="Cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</form>
```

I need some sort of validation when user punch in any input which dose not make sense in Time my Save btn should not be activated.

I appreciate your help and guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML `type="time"` or if you want more you can simply use a library like: `JsDaddy/ngx-mask` found on Github. Use it like this:

HTML with MatInput:

```
<input formControlName="Time" matInput placeholder="Time" type="time" />
```

With `ngx-mas`:

```
<input formControlName="Time" matInput placeholder="Time" mask="Hh:m0" />
```

Adding `type="time"` in all input time type use cases always help.

Comment: Thank you so much.Just for my own information, what dose  mask="Hh:m0" dose? U dud bit see anything by using it @Thomas

Comment: Oh sorry , i quess I should import the library first

Comment: Mask is used to guide a user's input where you would like them to enter the data in a certain format, such as dates, phone numbers, credit card, social security number, ZIpcode+4, IP address (IPv4, IPv6), software produce GUIDs and in your case `time`. When the built-in HTML5 types don't satisfy your use cases you can always customize your own, in JavaScript or use a library. Practically any input or data requested can be masked. It's a `sort` of validation on the input (but not the correctness of the data itself. You would still want to do data validation on the backend.